# Have a value fall off a report after a certain amount of days

Tags: sql, sql-server

Edited

What I'm trying to do is have customer information fall off of my report for 35 days when someone approves of it. I'm currently using the code

```
    CASE WHEN action_code_no = '15' and result_code_no = '93' then 
    datediff(Day,data.date,GETDATE()-35) end <= data.date
```

my desired result is to get data.date Which is an INT back down to 0, the report is set up so that when data.date reaches 35 it populates the report and when the action code = 15 and result code = 93 I want it to subtract 35 from data.date, hope this edit helps

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  It is entirely unclear what those codes have to do wth any approval.

Comment: and my apologies @GordonLinoff I'll make sure to include all of that the first time around in my next question. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to use dateAdd() instead:

```
CASE WHEN action_code_no = '15' and result_code_no = '93' then 
    dateAdd(Day,35, data.date) end > getDate()
```